# How to prevent my tex automatically split to two pages?

Tags: page-breaking

Here is my [tex file](https://gist.github.com/fuhailin/593cedcab634419c61301134ef60534a), I want to print the pdf file on one page A4 paper, but pdflatex gives me two pages result automatically, how to show the content on one page?
[image]

Comment: Try to use the `geometry` package to reduce the margins...

Comment: As you have not shown the source it is not really possible to tell you what to change. I would _guess_ that you are not allowing column breaks in each section so unless you make the page longer the POSIX section has to go on  to column two so the text will not fit.  So you can make the page size bigger (smaller margins) or make the font smaller or allow the posix section to split over column 1/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used the geometry package from Paul Gaborits comment and removed some setlengths and added columnseperation.

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

% Packages
\usepackage{fancyhdr}           % For header and footer
\usepackage{multicol}           % Allows multicols in tables
\usepackage{tabularx}           % Intelligent column widths
\usepackage{tabulary}           % Used in header and footer
\usepackage{hhline}             % Border under tables
\usepackage{graphicx}           % For images
\usepackage{xcolor}             % For hex colours
%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}    % For unicode character support
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % Without this we get weird character replacements
\usepackage{colortbl}           % For coloured tables
\usepackage{setspace}           % For line height
\usepackage{lastpage}           % Needed for total page number
\usepackage{seqsplit}           % Splits long words.
%\usepackage{opensans}          % Can't make this work so far. Shame. Would be lovely.
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}     % For underlining links
% Most of the following are not required for the majority
% of cheat sheets but are needed for some symbol support.
\usepackage{amsmath}            % Symbols
\usepackage{MnSymbol}           % Symbols
\usepackage{wasysym}            % Symbols
%\usepackage[english,german,french,spanish,italian]{babel}              % Languages


% Lengths and widths
\addtolength{\textwidth}{6cm} 
%removed stuff here
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.2cm} % Space between columns
\setlength{\headsep}{-12pt} % Reduce space between header and content
\setlength{\headheight}{85pt} % If less, LaTeX automatically increases it

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove footer line
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove header line
\renewcommand{\seqinsert}{\ifmmode\allowbreak\else\-\fi} % Hyphens in seqsplit
% This two commands together give roughly
% the right line height in the tables
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\onehalfspacing

% Commands
\newcommand{\SetRowColor}[1]{\noalign{\gdef\RowColorName{#1}}\rowcolor{\RowColorName}} % Shortcut for row colour
\newcommand{\mymulticolumn}[3]{\multicolumn{#1}{>{\columncolor{\RowColorName}}#2}{#3}} % For coloured multi-cols
\newcolumntype{x}[1]{>{\raggedright}p{#1}} % New column types for ragged-right paragraph columns
\newcommand{\tn}{\tabularnewline} % Required as custom column type in use

% Font and Colours
\definecolor{HeadBackground}{HTML}{333333}
\definecolor{FootBackground}{HTML}{666666}
\definecolor{TextColor}{HTML}{333333}
\definecolor{DarkBackground}{HTML}{C10443}
\definecolor{LightBackground}{HTML}{F4D4DF}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\color{TextColor}
\newenvironment{absolutelynopagebreak}



\setlength{\columnsep}{2cm}  % added
\usepackage[a4paper,total={170mm,257mm}, % added
left=5mm,
top=5mm,]{geometry}


\begin{document}
\begin{absolutelynopagebreak}
\raggedright
\raggedcolumns

% Set font size to small. Switch to any value
% from this page to resize cheat sheet text:
% www.emerson.emory.edu/services/latex/latex_169.html
\footnotesize % Small font.

\begin{multicols*}{3}

\begin{tabularx}{5.377cm}{p{0.4977 cm} x{4.4793 cm} }
\SetRowColor{DarkBackground}
\mymulticolumn{2}{x{5.377cm}}{\bf\textcolor{white}{Anchors}}  \tn
% Row 0
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
\textasciicircum{} & Start of string, or start of line in multi-line pattern \tn 
% Row Count 2 (+ 2)
% Row 1
\SetRowColor{white}
\textbackslash{}A & Start of string \tn 
% Row Count 3 (+ 1)
% Row 2
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
\$ & End of string, or end of line in multi-line pattern \tn 
% Row Count 5 (+ 2)
% Row 3
\SetRowColor{white}
\textbackslash{}Z & End of string \tn 
% Row Count 6 (+ 1)
% Row 4
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
\textbackslash{}b & Word boundary \tn 
% Row Count 7 (+ 1)
% Row 5
\SetRowColor{white}
\textbackslash{}B & Not word boundary \tn 
% Row Count 8 (+ 1)
% Row 6
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
\textbackslash{}\textless{} & Start of word \tn 
% Row Count 9 (+ 1)
% Row 7
\SetRowColor{white}
\textbackslash{}\textgreater{} & End of word \tn 
% Row Count 10 (+ 1)
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{DarkBackground}}--}
\end{tabularx}
\par\addvspace{1.3em}

\begin{tabularx}{5.377cm}{p{0.54747 cm} x{4.42953 cm} }
\SetRowColor{DarkBackground}
\mymulticolumn{2}{x{5.377cm}}{\bf\textcolor{white}{Character Classes}}  \tn
% Row 0
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
\textbackslash{}c & Control character \tn 
% Row Count 1 (+ 1)
% Row 1
\SetRowColor{white}
\textbackslash{}s & White space \tn 
% Row Count 2 (+ 1)
% Row 2
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
\textbackslash{}S & Not white space \tn 
% Row Count 3 (+ 1)
% Row 3
\SetRowColor{white}
\textbackslash{}d & Digit \tn 
% Row Count 4 (+ 1)
% Row 4
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
\textbackslash{}D & Not digit \tn 
% Row Count 5 (+ 1)
% Row 5
\SetRowColor{white}
\textbackslash{}w & Word \tn 
% Row Count 6 (+ 1)
% Row 6
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
\textbackslash{}W & Not word \tn 
% Row Count 7 (+ 1)
% Row 7
\SetRowColor{white}
\textbackslash{}x & Hexadecimal digit \tn 
% Row Count 8 (+ 1)
% Row 8
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
\textbackslash{}O & Octal digit \tn 
% Row Count 9 (+ 1)
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{DarkBackground}}--}
\end{tabularx}
\par\addvspace{1.3em}

\begin{tabularx}{5.377cm}{x{2.04057 cm} x{2.93643 cm} }
\SetRowColor{DarkBackground}
\mymulticolumn{2}{x{5.377cm}}{\bf\textcolor{white}{POSIX}}  \tn
% Row 0
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
\{\{nobreak\}\}{[}:upper:{]} & Upper case letters \tn 
% Row Count 2 (+ 2)
% Row 1
\SetRowColor{white}
\{\{nobreak\}\}{[}:lower:{]} & Lower case letters \tn 
% Row Count 4 (+ 2)
% Row 2
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
\{\{nobreak\}\}{[}:alpha:{]} & All letters \tn 
% Row Count 6 (+ 2)
% Row 3
\SetRowColor{white}
\{\{nobreak\}\}{[}:alnum:{]} & Digits and letters \tn 
% Row Count 8 (+ 2)
% Row 4
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
\{\{nobreak\}\}{[}:digit:{]} & Digits \tn 
% Row Count 10 (+ 2)
% Row 5
\SetRowColor{white}
\{\{nobreak\}\}{[}:xdigit:{]} & Hexadecimal digits \tn 
% Row Count 12 (+ 2)
% Row 6
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
\{\{nobreak\}\}{[}:punct:{]} & Punctuation \tn 
% Row Count 14 (+ 2)
% Row 7
\SetRowColor{white}
\{\{nobreak\}\}{[}:blank:{]} & Space and tab \tn 
% Row Count 16 (+ 2)
% Row 8
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
\{\{nobreak\}\}{[}:space:{]} & Blank characters \tn 
% Row Count 18 (+ 2)
% Row 9
\SetRowColor{white}
\{\{nobreak\}\}{[}:cntrl:{]} & Control characters \tn 
% Row Count 20 (+ 2)
% Row 10
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
\{\{nobreak\}\}{[}:graph:{]} & Printed characters \tn 
% Row Count 22 (+ 2)
% Row 11
\SetRowColor{white}
\{\{nobreak\}\}{[}:print:{]} & Printed characters and spaces \tn 
% Row Count 24 (+ 2)
% Row 12
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
\{\{nobreak\}\}{[}:word:{]} & Digits, letters and underscore \tn 
% Row Count 26 (+ 2)
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{DarkBackground}}--}
\end{tabularx}
\par\addvspace{1.3em}

\begin{tabularx}{5.377cm}{x{1.44333 cm} x{3.53367 cm} }
\SetRowColor{DarkBackground}
\mymulticolumn{2}{x{5.377cm}}{\bf\textcolor{white}{Assertions}}  \tn
% Row 0
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
?= & Lookahead assertion \tn 
% Row Count 1 (+ 1)
% Row 1
\SetRowColor{white}
?! & Negative lookahead \tn 
% Row Count 2 (+ 1)
% Row 2
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
?\textless{}= & Lookbehind assertion \tn 
% Row Count 3 (+ 1)
% Row 3
\SetRowColor{white}
?!= or ?\textless{}! & Negative lookbehind \tn 
% Row Count 4 (+ 1)
% Row 4
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
?\textgreater{} & Once-only Subexpression \tn 
% Row Count 5 (+ 1)
% Row 5
\SetRowColor{white}
?() & Condition {[}if then{]} \tn 
% Row Count 6 (+ 1)
% Row 6
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
?()| & Condition {[}if then else{]} \tn 
% Row Count 7 (+ 1)
% Row 7
\SetRowColor{white}
?\# & Comment \tn 
% Row Count 8 (+ 1)
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{DarkBackground}}--}
\end{tabularx}
\par\addvspace{1.3em}

\begin{tabularx}{5.377cm}{p{0.4177 cm} x{1.29487 cm} p{0.87717 cm} x{1.58726 cm} }
\SetRowColor{DarkBackground}
\mymulticolumn{4}{x{5.377cm}}{\bf\textcolor{white}{Quantifiers}}  \tn
% Row 0
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
* & 0 or more & \{3\} & Exactly 3 \tn 
% Row Count 1 (+ 1)
% Row 1
\SetRowColor{white}
+ & 1 or more & \{3,\} & 3 or more \tn 
% Row Count 2 (+ 1)
% Row 2
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
? & 0 or 1 & \{3,5\} & 3, 4 or 5 \tn 
% Row Count 3 (+ 1)
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{DarkBackground}}----}
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
\mymulticolumn{4}{x{5.377cm}}{Add a ? to a quantifier to make it ungreedy.}  \tn 
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{DarkBackground}}----}
\end{tabularx}
\par\addvspace{1.3em}

\begin{tabularx}{5.377cm}{p{0.4977 cm} x{4.4793 cm} }
\SetRowColor{DarkBackground}
\mymulticolumn{2}{x{5.377cm}}{\bf\textcolor{white}{Escape Sequences}}  \tn
% Row 0
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
\textbackslash{} & Escape following character \tn 
% Row Count 1 (+ 1)
% Row 1
\SetRowColor{white}
\textbackslash{}Q & Begin literal sequence \tn 
% Row Count 2 (+ 1)
% Row 2
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
\textbackslash{}E & End literal sequence \tn 
% Row Count 3 (+ 1)
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{DarkBackground}}--}
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
\mymulticolumn{2}{x{5.377cm}}{"Escaping" is a way of treating characters which have a special meaning in regular expressions literally, rather than as special characters.}  \tn 
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{DarkBackground}}--}
\end{tabularx}
\par\addvspace{1.3em}

\begin{tabularx}{5.377cm}{p{1.04425 cm} p{1.04425 cm} p{1.04425 cm} p{1.04425 cm} }
\SetRowColor{DarkBackground}
\mymulticolumn{4}{x{5.377cm}}{\bf\textcolor{white}{Common Metacharacters}}  \tn
% Row 0
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
\textasciicircum{} & {[} & . & \$ \tn 
% Row Count 1 (+ 1)
% Row 1
\SetRowColor{white}
\{ & * & ( & \textbackslash{} \tn 
% Row Count 2 (+ 1)
% Row 2
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
+ & ) & | & ? \tn 
% Row Count 3 (+ 1)
% Row 3
\SetRowColor{white}
\textless{} & \textgreater{} &  &  \tn 
% Row Count 4 (+ 1)
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{DarkBackground}}----}
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
\mymulticolumn{4}{x{5.377cm}}{The escape character is usually \textbackslash{}}  \tn 
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{DarkBackground}}----}
\end{tabularx}
\par\addvspace{1.3em}

\begin{tabularx}{5.377cm}{p{0.84609 cm} x{4.13091 cm} }
\SetRowColor{DarkBackground}
\mymulticolumn{2}{x{5.377cm}}{\bf\textcolor{white}{Special Characters}}  \tn
% Row 0
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
\textbackslash{}n & New line \tn 
% Row Count 1 (+ 1)
% Row 1
\SetRowColor{white}
\textbackslash{}r & Carriage return \tn 
% Row Count 2 (+ 1)
% Row 2
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
\textbackslash{}t & Tab \tn 
% Row Count 3 (+ 1)
% Row 3
\SetRowColor{white}
\textbackslash{}v & Vertical tab \tn 
% Row Count 4 (+ 1)
% Row 4
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
\textbackslash{}f & Form feed \tn 
% Row Count 5 (+ 1)
% Row 5
\SetRowColor{white}
\textbackslash{}xxx & Octal character xxx \tn 
% Row Count 6 (+ 1)
% Row 6
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
\textbackslash{}xhh & Hex character hh \tn 
% Row Count 7 (+ 1)
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{DarkBackground}}--}
\end{tabularx}
\par\addvspace{1.3em}

\begin{tabularx}{5.377cm}{x{0.84609 cm} x{4.13091 cm} }
\SetRowColor{DarkBackground}
\mymulticolumn{2}{x{5.377cm}}{\bf\textcolor{white}{Groups and Ranges}}  \tn
% Row 0
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
. & Any character except new line (\textbackslash{}n) \tn 
% Row Count 2 (+ 2)
% Row 1
\SetRowColor{white}
(a|b) & a or b \tn 
% Row Count 3 (+ 1)
% Row 2
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
(...) & Group \tn 
% Row Count 4 (+ 1)
% Row 3
\SetRowColor{white}
\seqsplit{(?:...)} & Passive (non-capturing) group \tn 
% Row Count 6 (+ 2)
% Row 4
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
{[}abc{]} & Range (a or b or c) \tn 
% Row Count 7 (+ 1)
% Row 5
\SetRowColor{white}
{[}\textasciicircum{}abc{]} & Not (a or b or c) \tn 
% Row Count 8 (+ 1)
% Row 6
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
{[}a-q{]} & Lower case letter from a to q \tn 
% Row Count 9 (+ 1)
% Row 7
\SetRowColor{white}
{[}A-Q{]} & Upper case letter from A to Q \tn 
% Row Count 10 (+ 1)
% Row 8
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
{[}0-7{]} & Digit from 0 to 7 \tn 
% Row Count 11 (+ 1)
% Row 9
\SetRowColor{white}
\textbackslash{}x & Group/subpattern number "x" \tn 
% Row Count 12 (+ 1)
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{DarkBackground}}--}
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
\mymulticolumn{2}{x{5.377cm}}{Ranges are inclusive.}  \tn 
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{DarkBackground}}--}
\end{tabularx}
\par\addvspace{1.3em}

\begin{tabularx}{5.377cm}{x{0.84609 cm} x{4.13091 cm} }
\SetRowColor{DarkBackground}
\mymulticolumn{2}{x{5.377cm}}{\bf\textcolor{white}{Pattern Modifiers}}  \tn
% Row 0
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
g & Global match \tn 
% Row Count 1 (+ 1)
% Row 1
\SetRowColor{white}
i~* & Case-insensitive \tn 
% Row Count 3 (+ 2)
% Row 2
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
m~* & Multiple lines \tn 
% Row Count 5 (+ 2)
% Row 3
\SetRowColor{white}
s~* & Treat string as single line \tn 
% Row Count 7 (+ 2)
% Row 4
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
x~* & Allow comments and whitespace in pattern \tn 
% Row Count 9 (+ 2)
% Row 5
\SetRowColor{white}
e~* & Evaluate replacement \tn 
% Row Count 11 (+ 2)
% Row 6
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
U~* & Ungreedy pattern \tn 
% Row Count 13 (+ 2)
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{DarkBackground}}--}
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
\mymulticolumn{2}{x{5.377cm}}{* PCRE modifier}  \tn 
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{DarkBackground}}--}
\end{tabularx}
\par\addvspace{1.3em}

\begin{tabularx}{5.377cm}{p{0.4977 cm} x{4.4793 cm} }
\SetRowColor{DarkBackground}
\mymulticolumn{2}{x{5.377cm}}{\bf\textcolor{white}{String Replacement}}  \tn
% Row 0
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
\$n & nth non-passive group \tn 
% Row Count 1 (+ 1)
% Row 1
\SetRowColor{white}
\$2 & "xyz" in /\textasciicircum{}(abc(xyz))\$/ \tn 
% Row Count 2 (+ 1)
% Row 2
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
\$1 & "xyz" in /\textasciicircum{}(?:abc)(xyz)\$/ \tn 
% Row Count 3 (+ 1)
% Row 3
\SetRowColor{white}
\$` & Before matched string \tn 
% Row Count 4 (+ 1)
% Row 4
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
\$' & After matched string \tn 
% Row Count 5 (+ 1)
% Row 5
\SetRowColor{white}
\$+ & Last matched string \tn 
% Row Count 6 (+ 1)
% Row 6
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
\$\& & Entire matched string \tn 
% Row Count 7 (+ 1)
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{DarkBackground}}--}
\SetRowColor{LightBackground}
\mymulticolumn{2}{x{5.377cm}}{Some regex implementations use \textbackslash{} instead of \$.}  \tn 
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{DarkBackground}}--}
\end{tabularx}
\par\addvspace{1.3em}


% That's all folks
\end{multicols*}
\end{absolutelynopagebreak}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, you give me big help:) I love this platform